# Seeking on chrome audio player not working

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am trying to read a music from my backend on chrome / firefox/a ionic projet.
I cant click the timeline to chose a time I want to go to when I'm listening on google chrome or ionic music player. The music just restart from 00:00 when I do so . I tried doing a request from postman and it could read the music correctly and set the time I wanted when I clicked the timeline , same on firefox (its working correctly). However it does not work on chrome, as I said the music just restart when you click the timeline. Here is my backend route :

EDIT1 : my only hint is when I use howler.js as my player, if I pass the HTML5= true its not gonna work and if I dont put it its working, even if its open on chrome... (https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler) or maybe a header is missing ?

```
getMusic(req, res) {

        try {
            var trackID = new ObjectID(req.params.trackID);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid trackID in URL parameter. Must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters" });
        }
        res.set('content-type', 'audio/mpeg');
        res.set('accept-ranges', 'bytes');

        let bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db, {
            bucketName: 'tracks'
        });

        let downloadStream = bucket.openDownloadStream(trackID);

        downloadStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            res.write(chunk);
        });

        downloadStream.on('error', () => {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        });

        downloadStream.on('end', () => {
            res.end();
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Content-length" header was missing on this code and after trying it with a dummy it works. I just need to find how to get the music length now, so I close this post.

example `res.set('content-length', '5000000');`